# How to upload a File Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I receive paste image from clipboard, get a object like this:
[image]

Due to security reason, I cannot add it into a `<input>`. I tried to upload it directly with jquery post, like

`var d=new FormData()`

`d.append('blob',blob.__proto__);`

`contentType: false,processData: false,`

but just post a `[Object File]` to the server. So how can I post it as a normal image?

Comment: The so-called duplicate question is in no way related to the question asked here (which is about how to get a file object from the clipboard, not from a file input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pulling the `File` constructor function out of the File object's prototype and trying to upload that.

You need to upload the actual File object.

```
d.append('blob',blob);
```